# Building a group representation of genes' ontologies

Tags: gene, gene-ontology, ontology

I have a list of genes (about 2000) from lines of **drosophila subobscura**, in the following format:

- LOC117900589
- LOC11788959
- LOC11790331

I'm trying to represent this set of genes in a useful way.

So, I was recommended to represent the ontology function of these genes in a graphical way.
I was recommended this tool:
http://cbl-gorilla.cs.technion.ac.il/

One inputs a list of genes and it outputs this kind of graph:
[image: GOrilla example output]

The problem is that, this tool, GOrilla only accepts genes from **drosophila melanogaster**.

I have to either:

- **a)** convert the genes id to a homologous gene in **melanogaster**
- **b)** find an alternative tool

A solution to either a) or b) would be helpful. Or an alternative solution.

For a) I tried:

- Ncbi's **homologene**: which doesn't seem to be working for a the genes ID I tried so far (I didn't try them all)
- Blasting the gene sequence on melanogaster's genome and looking through the list manually to find an homologous gene.

So far these methods have been impractical for the number of genes I have.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [DAVID](https://david.ncifcrf.gov/summary.jsp) for functional annotation (Gene Ontology and KEGG terms)?

I usually use DAVID to extract GO and KEGG terms and plot the results using R.

If you also want to plot a protein-protein interaction (PPI) network for your gene list you can use STRING database to extract interactions and network and use Cytoscape for visualizing this result.

Comment: I tried putting a bunch of entrez id genes and I got nothing useful it seems? https://imgur.com/tZc6Vk8.png